# Weird picture taken from onPreviewFrame on Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to take a `Bitmap` from `onPreviewImage` on Android. The way to do it is well known in the community:

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromCameraBytes(Camera camera, byte[] bytes) {

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    int pWidth = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
    int pHeight = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(bytes, ImageFormat.NV21, pWidth, pHeight, null);

    yuv.compressToJpeg(new android.graphics.Rect(0, 0, pWidth, pHeight), 50, out);
    byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

}
```

so when I debug it, I got the size as well:

[image]

but if I play on `View bitmap`:

it says **1024x768** and it is really cropped.

[image]

what's wrong with that??

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Rafael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at the end it's an error of Android Studio, since I tried to draw the `Bitmap` into an `ImageView` and it was displaying perfectly.

Just in case anyone gets the same error!